# How to serialize repeated fields?

Tags: json, api, serialization, json.net

Currently I need the Json to look like this

```
[
 {
     "id": -2147483639,
     "parentId": 37
    },
    {
    "id": -2147483636,
    "parentId": 35
    }
]
```

In my framework I have model class with the following. How do I get the json to serialize to look like above when I have another set of attributes with the same name. And Also is this the most efficient way to Serialize. I am using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Model()); that is how I am Serializing it

```
Serializable]
    public class Model
    {
         public int id { get; set; }
         public int parentId { get; set; }

        public Model()
        {
            id = -2147483639; 
            parentId = 37; 

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, something like below should be able to give you an idea of how to go forward.  Note, I would remove the code you have in the constructor.  Most likely you would use a `List<Model>`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            List<Model> lm = new List<Model>();
            lm.Add(new Model() { id = 1000, parentId = 2000 });
            lm.Add(new Model() { id = 3000, parentId = 4000 });
            string sm = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lm);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I need my json to serialize to be like the above. Currently in my framework I have a class called model. I can not declare var data types their.

Comment: Uh, ok...I removed them.

Comment: I tried creating the List<model> lm = new List<Model>() but it does not allow me to add to the list using the reference in my class for some reason. It throws an error "The name lm does not exists in the current context"